# Symfony3 : get form field HTML name attribute from controller

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, error-handling, symfony

I am working on a controller which has to send a JSON encoded array with the errors of a form, in order to display them under each fields of the form with jQuery after an Ajax request.

To do that, I would need to be able to retrieve the HTML name attribute (or the id) of each field in order to find them in the DOM.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($form);
$errorsArray = [];
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    $field = str_replace('data.', '', $error->getPropertyPath());
    $message = $error->getMessage();

    $errorsArray[$field][] = $message;
}
```

Although, this returns for example `username` for an Entity `User`, but in the twig, it generates `user[username]`. Even worse, for nested forms (with one-to-one relationship), I get stuff like `user[group][id]`.

Is there a way to retrieve the name attribute that is given by the form in the Twig in order to format a proper JSON that would look like:

```
{
    0: {
         field: 'user[username]',
         errors: [
             'message of error 1',
             'message of error 2'
         ]
    },
    1: {
        field: 'user[group][id]',
        errors: [
             'message of error 1'
        ]
    }
}
```

Because in a normal array, string like user[username] would be difficult to have as an array key.

What do you think? Any idea?

Thank you very much,
Regards

Comment: I did not understand the problem o.O

Comment: I need to return a json to my Ajax call so that I can place the errors below each form fields in the DOM. However, the getPropertyPath returns something that doesn't reflect the fields attributes in the DOM. So I can't bind the errors messages in my DOM in JavaScript with the array my controller currently returns.

Comment: So you want to replace the default-like `name` attribute value for each form field with a more friendly ones, like `name="username"` instead of `name=appbundle[username]`?

Comment: That could be a solution, but I suppose I would need to add parameters to my fields in my AbstractType which would be used only to facilitate the mapping? And would this still work to map the attributes of my nested entity?